# node.js script, is there a way to prompt the user with a gui prompt?

Tags: node.js, windows, user-interface, prompt

I created a node.js script that runs in the background on a clients windows machine, triggered periodically by the windows task manager.

Before intervening with a local database I would have to prompt the user if that ok for now.

Is there a library or smthg that makes it possible to promt the user with a dialogue window?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Before the database call, you could write a new function inside which the code for a dialogue would be there and `await` it. You can use [dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialog) package for it.